# Evaluate integral

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

How do I evaluate the following integral, the answer according to Wolfram Alpha is $2$, but I keep on getting $0$ after using integration by parts.$$\frac12\int_{-\infty}^\infty x^2e^{-|x|}\ dx$$

Comment: Split the integral for the region $-\infty<x<0\ $ and $\ 0<x<\infty$.

Comment: It equals $\int_{0}^{\infty}x^{2}e^{-x}dx=\Gamma\left(3\right)=2$ because of
symmetry.

Comment: @Tunk-Fey That's probably not the asker's issue, since he/she is getting 0 as a result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\frac12\int_{-\infty}^\infty x^2e^{-|x|}dx
= \frac12\int_{-\infty}^0x^2e^{x}dx +\frac12\int_{0}^\infty x^2e^{-x}dx
\\
= \int_{0}^\infty x^2e^{-x}dx = [x^2(-e^{-x})]_{0}^\infty  + 2\int_{0}^\infty xe^{-x} dx
\\
=0+ 2[x(-e^{-x})]_{0}^\infty + 2\int_{0}^\infty e^{-x}dx = 0+0+2[(-e^{-x})]_{0}^\infty =2
$$

Answer (score 2):

Hint: By parity,
$$
\frac12\int_{-\infty}^\infty x^2e^{-\vert x \rvert}dx = \int_{0}^\infty x^2e^{- x }dx
$$
Then, use integration by parts, now that there is no absolute values to cause trouble.

It cannot be zero, as your function (which happens to be the second raw moment of a Laplace distribution, incidentally) is always positive (except at $0$).

Answer (score 2):

**Hint :**
$$
\int_{-\infty}^\infty x^2e^{-|x|}\ dx=\int_{-\infty}^0 x^2e^{x}\ dx+\int_{0}^\infty x^2e^{-x}\ dx=2\int_{0}^\infty x^2e^{-x}\ dx.
$$